# System.Text.Encoding conflict with System.Runtime

Tags: .net-core

After I've changed project.json to csproj I have compilation error:

> error CS0433: The type 'Encoding' exists in both 'System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

My csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And the code is something like that:

```
using System.Text;
...

var x = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xxx");
```

Could someone help?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the ```project.lock.json``` file? It might help

Comment: Not helped, I've event created new project in VS 2017 with csproj and have the same issue.

Comment: Same here, opened a perfectly fine solution in a week and got this conflict

Comment: To fix this I closed  VS2017, ran this command 'dotnet nuget locals all --clear' and re-opened the solution - now compiles successfully.